# What is webapp2's dispatch() method used for?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

I have built gae webapps without ever having to use the dispatch() method. I have encountered it while trying to work with `webapp2_extras.auth` but I don't fully understand its concept and how it fits in with the `get()` and `post()` methods. According to its brief documentation:

> Dispatches the request.
>       This will first check if there's a handler_method defined in the
>       matched route, and if not it'll use the method correspondent to the
>       request method (`get()`, `post()` etc).

My understanding is that it checks my routes to see if a handler class exists to handle a request, but isn't the `dispatch()` method defined within an existing handler class already? Also, isn't a request *dispatched* from the client-side?

I am confused about some of its use cases, especially in the context of `webapp_extras.auth`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/webapp2/blob/master/webapp2.py#L589) is probably the best place to start looking to understand this problem.

If we just look at the last couple lines,

```
try:
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
except Exception, e:
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
```

It's calling a method and, if that method call fails with an exception, it calls the `handle_exception` method.  So, this explains the magic of `handle_exception`.

The rest of the function is

1. Looking at the request and figuring out which method to call (`get`, `post`, `put`, `delete`, ...) and determining if the handler supports that method.
2. Figuring out if any additional arguments are supposed to be passed to the handler.

---

As for how it plays with `webapp2_extras.auth`, I think that depends on what you are trying to do.  I suppose you could create a handler subclass that checks if the user is logged in:

```
class AuthedHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def dispatch(self):
        # Check of user is authenticated, otherwise redirect or 
        # return error response.
        super(AuthedHandler, self).dispatch()
```

Comment: Doesn't the request handler already know which methods to call? For example, if a form is submitted with `method="get"`, then isn't that request automatically dispatched to the `get(self)` method?

Comment: @haopei -- The `WSGIApplication` dispatches the request to a handler via the router (through the `default_dispatcher` method).  Once the request gets to the handler, it is up to the handler to determine what method the request corresponds to.  `dispatch` is the method responsible for picking the method and calling it.